# Two SOUTH JPanels with buttons

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I want to add two JPanels with FlowLayout in the bottom of the frame. This is the code:

```
public Triangle(String title)
{
    super(title);
    a = getContentPane();
    a.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    a.setForeground(new Color(100, 200, 100));
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
    p2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    p4.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    p1.add(l1);
    p1.add(stranaa);
    p1.add(l2);
    p1.add(stranab);
    p1.add(l3);
    p1.add(stranac);
    p2.add(per);
    p2.add(proverka);
    p4.add(clear);
    p4.add(exit);
    p3.add(l4);
    a.add(p3, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    a.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    a.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    a.add(p4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

but then nothing happens, only the this in p4 are show and these in p2 are hidden somewhere. Help?

Comment: Group the first 3 into one panel and use another panel to put the previous panel center and last one south

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height. 3) Your IDE has nothing to do with this.  Don't add it as a tag.  I added two tags that were more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Create additional panel (i.e. southPanel), add your p2 and p4 to it and then: `a.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);`

For example:

```
JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
southPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout());  // Use what is suitable for you
southPanel.add(p2);
southPanel.add(p4);
a.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add one south panel. If you add more than one south panel than last one will override other panel. If you want to show both than introduce new one

```
JPanel p2p4=new JPanel();
p2p4.add(p2);
p2p4.add(p4);

a.add(p2p4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: But I would like to have two lines with buttons.

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
JPanel south = new JPanel();
south.add(p2);
south.add(p4);
a.add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I make p4 go under p2?

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested group

```
JPanel p2p4 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
p2p4.add(p2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
p2p4.add(p4, BorderLayout.CENTER);

a.add(p2p4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```